# Parsing and rearranging text data in R to add a tab

Tags: regex, r, replace

I have a text data (mydata.txt) which I will like to rearrange.

mydata.txt:

```
241623..243414 product="Putative sulfate permease"
complement(344599..354507) product="Alcohol dehydrogenase (EC 1.1.1.1)"
tRNA 168479..169551 product="tRNA-Val-GAC"
```

My intention was to move the part of every line starting with "product=.."   further away from the first part of the text by a tab (\t) as follows:

```
241623..243414  product="Putative sulfate permease"
complement(344599..354507)  product="Alcohol dehydrogenase (EC 1.1.1.1)"
tRNA 168479..169551 product="tRNA-Val-GAC"
```

My attempt so far:

```
x <- sub("(^\\.)(\\product=\\S+)$","\\1", mydata)
y <- sub("(^\\.)(\\product=\\S+)$","\\2", mydata)
```

All I'm getting is some numerical values as output in each case. Can someone help me please? Thanks.

Comment: Hmm. What exactly was your regular expression supposed to match?

Answer (score 3):

Make some test data corresponding to your example:

```
test <- c(
  "241623..243414 product=\"Putative sulfate permease\"",
  "complement(344599..354507) product=\"Alcohol dehydrogenase (EC 1.1.1.1)\"",
  "tRNA 168479..169551 product=\"tRNA-Val-GAC\""
)
```

Run the `sub` function to add a tab (`\t`):

```
result <- sub("\\s+(product=)","\t\\1",test)
```

Results:

```
> cat(result[1])
241623..243414  product="Putative sulfate permease"> 

> cat(result[2])
complement(344599..354507)      product="Alcohol dehydrogenase (EC 1.1.1.1)"> 

> cat(result[3])
tRNA 168479..169551     product="tRNA-Val-GAC">
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to do that for every `product=` you may just

```
library(stringr)
x <- '241623..243414  product="Putative sulfate permease"
      complement(344599..354507)  product="Alcohol dehydrogenase (EC 1.1.1.1)"
      tRNA 168479..169551 product="tRNA-Val-GAC"'
str_replace_all(x, "product=", "\tproduct=")
```

This will give you

```
241623..243414      product="Putative sulfate permease"
complement(344599..354507)      product="Alcohol dehydrogenase (EC 1.1.1.1)"
tRNA 168479..169551     product="tRNA-Val-GAC"
```

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the codes. I forgot to mention that I have thousands of rows of these texts, and would like to read from file. I used read.delim for this purpose, but none of the two codes worked in this context. Is there any way out?